# Error when I want to rename the files generated in a for loop in powerShell

Tags: powershell, rename-item-cmdlet

Here is my for loop

```
function Generate_bin($input_1, $bin_file_name, $Codes){

   $counter=1 
   foreach ($Code in $Codes)
   {
      Write-Host "Code = $Code" 
      $input_11 = "$input_1" + "$counter"
      $pattern = "0x"
      $New = ""
      $Code = [regex]::replace($Code, $pattern, "$New")
      $bin_file_name2 = "$bin_file_name"
      $bin_file_name2 += "$Code" + ".bin"
      #This utility generates "out.bin"
       Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {.\xyz.exe -i -t "$input_1"}

      Rename-Item out.bin -NewName $bin_file_name2
      $counter++
   }

}
```

I am getting following error

```
Rename-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
At C:\script\myParser_unique.ps1:18 char:7
+       Rename-Item out.bin -NewName $bin_file_name2
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\v-ashi...Unified\out.bin:String) [Rename-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RenameItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameItemCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add -Force parameter to the Rename-Item to make it overwrite existing files.

If your code happens to generate multiple equal file names you could  add a counter to the filename.

Comment: thanks for reply. -Force didn`t worked for me. So I did following workaround    if (Test-Path $bin_file_name) 
   { 
        rm $bin_file_name 
   }
   Rename-Item out.bin -NewName $bin_file_name

Comment: Just use `rm -force -ea 0`